# mySQL insert only when not exists but with more conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a table `product_pushjobs with` 5 columns: id, user, product, connection, done`
ID is primary and auto increment.

For insert, I only fill in `user` and `product` (sometimes `connection`, depending on situation)

I want to prevent the insert when there is an other row with `user` and `product`, but **only if** `done IS NULL`.
So the table can have a million rows of the same user and product, but not when there is one that has a `done is NULL` .

I found a lot different suggestions here on this site, but not exactly the same as mine.
I've tried this, but have me an error:

```
INSERT INTO product_pushjobs (user, product) 
VALUES (5,9936) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM product_pushjobs 
    WHERE user=5 AND product=9936 AND connection IS NULL AND done IS NULL
)
```

mysql error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_pushjobs WHERE user=5
> AND product=9936 A' at line 1

I'm guessing it will be a stupid problem, but one that I need to fix fast.

Comment: Replace VALUES with SELECT and remove the parentheses from `(5,9936)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INSERT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/) statement does not have the possibility to add a WHERE-clause to it.

So, you could to:

```
INSERT INTO product_pushjobs (user, product) 
    SELECT 5,9936 WHERE (SELECT 1 
                           FROM product_pushjobs 
                           WHERE user=5 
                             AND product=9936 
                             AND connection IS NULL 
                             AND done IS NULL) IS NULL
```

The result from the query `SELECT 5,9936....` is used for input to the `INSERT` statement, but there is no result. The WHERE-clause makes sure only a record is returned if the record-to-insert is not already present.

`SELECT 1` could also be `SELECT id`, but since nothing is done with `id`, i choose to put `1` in that place.

Comment: Thanks!!! This does exactly what it needs to do. Hope the same query will work (for other tables) in prepared statements.